# How can I make my follower cut it out with all the jibber jabber?

Tags: diablo-iii

During the first playthrough, I enjoyed my follower's bits of dialog as we adventured since it was all new, but as I continue on through nightmare, I'm getting really sick of hearing the same things over and over again. We'll be running around the dungeon and the Enchantress will blathering on again about how I seem sad or whatever for the 432nd time while I'm trying to focus and get my demon slaying on. I just want my follower to zip their lips and shut up.

Is there any way to disable this dialogue?

Comment: Man, I was hoping for some sort of Mr. T image in this question...

Comment: @bwarner It was definitely hard to resist.

Comment: Use a different follower to get some new chit chat!

Comment: But The Light is both the literal *and* figurative enemy of Evil!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't politely ask favors of your followers, so **turn your Voice Volume to zero** instead.

I thought I'd miss the dialogue, but, after several playthroughs, I haven't changed it back.

[image: Voice Volume]

Comment: Does this hit all the NPCs, including shopkeepers, Azmo taunting you, etc? Still think it's worth it even it if does!

Comment: Yes, all voice parts are muted. A small price to pay, methinks

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  Blizzard has aimed to make the controls for Diablo as simple as possible, so omitted a lot of options that might have been useful.  Your only option is to not adventure with a follower in tow.

Comment: Not true, there is a lot of hidden controls for the veteran RPGer, such as monster health bars, advanced skill tooltips and one-click disabling of sound and music.

Comment: But you have to admit there a lot more options that people are asking about now that they're using Diablo 3 that simply aren't there.  Just have a look through the tagged questions and see how often the answer is "No, that option doesn't exist". :(

Answer (score 0):

One option (although not a practical one and not a good idea) is to edit your MPQ files.

All Blizzard games store their data (art, models, sounds, tabular data) in MPQ files, which you can think of as huge zip files. It is possible to extract this data (this is how datamining sites get some game information), and it's possible to edit some of the data and re-save the MPQ archives.

In the past (ie, for WoW), you could do things like change sound effects, change your login screen background, and shady things like making enemy models more visible in PvP.

For these reasons, and because the MPQ files are a proprietary format by Blizzard, editing MPQ files is **unsupported** and generally a **bad idea**. It could also get your **account flagged/locked** for hacking the game or cheating.

For this reason I will not provide any links. *Do not do this. Mess up your MPQ files at your own risk. Void where prohibited. Prohibited where void. Do not pass go and collect 200 gold coins.*

Comment: You can override files inside MPQs by recreating the folder structure in the `Data` (`Data_D3`) folder and saving a file there. At least this works great in WoW (and also doesn't get you banned - that was even confirmed in a blue post) so I guess it works in D3, too.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I thought at one point they disabled MPQ file overrides. I may be mistaken though.

Comment: At least a few months ago I could still replacy my WoW fishing sounds with easily hearable ones

Comment: @ThiefMaster Good deal then, A similar arrangement might work with D3 then. If so, this would be less risky as far as getting banned, although still unsupported.

Comment: @ThiefMaster this is what I do with WoW, I have a 'Sounds' folder that has blank audio files in it to replace all the NPC speech and attack sounds. Not sure if a similar pack exists for Diablo 3 yet...